# All my internet connections have disintegrated

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager, ethernet

Up until last week I had no problems. I have a Dell Latitude 3340 which was bought with 14.04 a couple of years ago and I recently upgraded to 16.04. And everything was fine. I'm a dev and use Vagrant - but I'm no expert with Linux (I just write code).

When trying to install a new VM I did a couple of stupid things (changing permissions for whole folders). So I screwed up sudoers but sorted that out.

Then I lost wireless. It just vanished. But ethernet was fine, and then that broke. And now I have nothing. OK, that's the background.

I've been at this for a couple of days, and I've read and tried everything I could find but nothing is improving (in some ways worse). Permissions may be an issue I already found one place where the suggested permissions fix was too restrictive

At the very least I need to get the ethernet back. But wireless would be good.

Here's all the data I think you'll need:

Results from `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev bb)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:c470]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Results from `lspci | egrep -i 'network|ethernet'`:

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-LM (rev 04)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev bb)

Results from `lshw -C network`:
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I218-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 04
       serial: 20:47:47:12:68:40
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.6-4 ip=192.168.1.149 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:42 memory:f7e00000-f7e1ffff memory:f7e3c000-f7e3cfff ioport:f080(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: bb
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: irq:47 memory:f7c00000-f7c01fff
```

Results from `nmcli d`:

```
DEVICE           TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION         
br-5de25754fda4  bridge    connected  br-5de25754fda4    
docker0          bridge    connected  docker0            
eth0             ethernet  connected  Wired connection 1 
lo               loopback  unmanaged  --
```

Results from `ifconfig`:

```
br-5de25754fda4 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:8f:0e:ca:d0  
          inet addr:172.18.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:80:b1:f0:c8  
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:47:47:12:68:40  
          inet addr:192.168.1.149  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::50ee:e26f:5e57:7d64/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2801 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:597 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:349073 (349.0 KB)  TX bytes:77039 (77.0 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7e00000-f7e20000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:10832 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10832 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:811344 (811.3 KB)  TX bytes:811344 (811.3 KB)
```

Results from `ip a`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 20:47:47:12:68:40 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.149/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 85423sec preferred_lft 85423sec
    inet6 fe80::50ee:e26f:5e57:7d64/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:80:b1:f0:c8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: br-5de25754fda4: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:8f:0e:ca:d0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 scope global br-5de25754fda4
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Results from `cat /etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

I have tried this:

```
sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
```

So that empty file still exists on the system.

And as a final note: On the front end it claims I'm connected to ethernet when I first switch on. I can then disconnect but when I re-connect it instantly disconnects again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two "bridge" interfaces are surely the problem.
This is my stdout for nmcli -d

```
DISPOSITIVO  TIPO      ESTADO       CONEXIÓN           
eth0         ethernet  conectado    Wired connection 1 
wlan0        wifi      conectado    WiFilibr3     
lo           loopback  sin gestión  --
```

You should bring down the interfaces

```
sudo ifconfig docker0 down
sudo ifconfig br-5de25754fda4 down
```

And modify your **/etc/network/interfaces** which should only have

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

That should be enough.

Comment: Hi, yeah. So I carried out your suggestions. Unfortunately, now, "Ethernet Network" is in the dropdown but unselectable. I'll keep searching but if you have any other suggestions that would be great.

Just re-did nmcli (after reboot) `eth0` is showing as unavailable, and the other two (docker & br) are back.

Comment: D'oh! I hadn't plugged in the network cable. OK. Now it claims it's connected but `ping google.com` fails (unknown host), `ping localhost` is fine.

Comment: And `ping 8.8.8.8` also worked. I found that all the DNS was gone. I could fix it by manually editing the `/run/.../resolv.conf` file. This gave me the space to force a reinstall of the NetworkManager. Which gave me back the wireless interface.

BUT still no DNS. Every time the system is restarted any change is wiped out.

Comment: Anyway technically the question is solved - I have Internet access back on both ethernet and wireless. So thanks.